# How can I move data from SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

I have created my database and tables in a SQL Server Express database. And now I migrated the database tables to Oracle with Entity Framework. But my tables are empty in Oracle. How can I move my data to Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS  interface from MS-SQL (Sql Server Integration Service).

I have used to move content from MSSQL to MySQL you should use the correct odbc driver.

Comment: Sorry, now I saw that you are using express edition .....
I will move the database on standard edition and export from there.

Answer (score 0):

For express edition, You can use **Linked Servers** to establish connection between SQL Server and Oracle. In this way, you should insert the records by creating queries for per table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine